# socket.io is not working in ionic build

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, chat, webrtc, crosswalk

I am using socket.io with nodejs express in the serverside. I am following this guide https://www.sitepoint.com/using-socket-io-and-cordova-to-create-a-real-time-chat-app/

This is working fine when I run the app in `ionic serve` in the web browser. But when I make a build and run from by actual device. it can't connect to server. I have run the server code in public ip accessible from anywhere.
I have also added the `crosswalk` plugin for getting webview and webrtc enabled; but still not working in cordova build. Can anyone help me where is missing I am doing here?

Many Thanks,
Zahirul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem installing white-list plugin that was missing. In  a fresh project creation with ionic latest version this plugin is added automatically.